# MapControl get tapped location UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I have a MapControl in my app and I want to retrieve the coordinate of the point taped by the user.

```
<Maps:MapControl    Grid.Row="0" 
                    ColorScheme="Light" 
                    Margin="10" 
                    x:Name="mainMap" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Tapped="mainMap_Tapped"
                    MapElementClick="mainMap_MapElementClick"
                />
```

But I don't know how to get this from the event `private void mainMap_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the tapped location in MapControl, we can use **[MapControl.MapTapped event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.maptapped.aspx)**. This event occurs when the user taps the **[MapControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.aspx)** or clicks on it with the left mouse button. An instance of **[MapInputEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapinputeventargs.aspx)** provides data for this event. And in `MapInputEventArgs`, we can get the location with [**MapInputEventArgs.Location property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapinputeventargs.location.aspx). For example:

In XAML:

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="mainMap"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Margin="10"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 ColorScheme="Light"
                 MapTapped="mainMap_MapTapped"
                 MapElementClick="mainMap_MapElementClick" />
```

In code-behind:

```
private void mainMap_MapTapped(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapInputEventArgs args)
{
    var tappedGeoPosition = args.Location.Position;
    string status = "MapTapped at \nLatitude:" + tappedGeoPosition.Latitude + "\nLongitude: " + tappedGeoPosition.Longitude;
    rootPage.NotifyUser( status, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
```

Comment: can we get  location for Holding event?

Answer (score 1):

```
GeoPoint geoPt = this.mainMap.Layers[0].ScreenToGeoPoint(e.GetPosition(this.mapControl1));
```

Should get you the geopoint.

Comment: I got the `Layers[0]` underlined saying that there is no method

Comment: @SvenBorden That would be because you used parenthesis "( )" instead of brackets "[ ]", meaning you tried to call a method instead of reference a index

Comment: it also says that no definition for "Layers" and no method extension "Layers" accepts a first argument of type MapControl could be found
(btw thanks a lot)