# Bing Maps GeoPosition on Mouse Click

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I was wondering if anyone has an example of how to extract the geoposition(Lat,Lon) from a mouse click on the Bing Maps control. Pretty much I am launching the maps control, and I need to be able to take the Coordinates that are chosen via mouse click(double click) and pass them back into my UWP app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MapControl get tapped location UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617385/mapcontrol-get-tapped-location-uwp)

Answer (score 2):

```html
private void Map_MapTapped(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapInputEventArgs args)
{
    var GeoPosition = args.Location.Position;
    string status = "MapTapped at \nLatitude:" + GeoPosition.Latitude + "\nLongitude: " + GeoPosition.Longitude;
    rootPage.NotifyUser( status, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
```

here is a answer